# yyparse() not declared in Bison/Flex C++ project only for some version of gcc/bison/flex

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer

First of all I'm pretty new to Bison and Flex. I know those tools were designed to be used in C and I have a feeling all of my problem comes from using them in C++. I'm not sure I've done it the right way.

The code compiles fine on my computer but doesn't on my university server. I've isolated the issue to post here.

At my university:

```
$ (g++ --version; bison --version; flex --version)|grep '[0-9]\.'
g++ (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5
bison (GNU Bison) 2.4.1
flex 2.5.35
```

At home:

```
HOME $ (g++ --version; bison --version; flex --version)|grep '[0-9]\.'
g++ (GCC) 4.7.1 20120721 (prerelease)
bison (GNU Bison) 2.6.2
flex 2.5.37
```

I use the following command to compile:
`bison -d parse.y && flex lex.l && g++ main.cpp lex.yy.c parse.tab.c -lfl`

As I already said, it compiles fine (no warnings) on my computer but I get this on the server:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:28: error: 'yyparse' was not declared in this scope
```

Since SO has some problem with brackets, [I've also uploaded a tarball](http://diobla.info/code/parse.tgz).

lex.l

```
%{
#include 
#include "dict.hpp"
#include "parse.tab.h"
%}

%%

[0-9]+  yylval.num = atoi(yytext); return NUM;
[a-z]+  yylval.id = dict.id(yytext); return ID;
[:space:]   ;
```

parse.y

```
%{
#include 
#include "dict.hpp"
void yyerror (const char* e) {
    puts(e);
}
int yylex ();
%}

%union{
    uint id;
    int num;    
}

%token ID;
%token NUM;

%%

S : ID NUM S {
        dict.set($1, $2);
    }
|;
```

dict.hpp

```
#ifndef _DICT_HPP_
#define _DICT_HPP_
#include 
#include 

typedef std::pair dpair;
typedef unsigned int uint;

class Dict {
    std::vector tab;
public:
    uint id(char* s);
    void set(uint i, int v);
    void print();
};

extern Dict dict;

#endif /* _DICT_HPP_ */
```

main.cpp

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include "dict.hpp"
#include "parse.tab.h"

Dict dict;

uint Dict::id (char* s) {
    for(uint i = 0; i < tab.size(); i++)
        if(tab[i].first == s)
            return i;
    tab.push_back(dpair(std::string(s), tab.size()));
    return tab.size()-1;
}

void Dict::set (uint i, int v) {
    tab[i].second = v;
}

void Dict::print () {
    for(uint i = 0; i < tab.size(); i++)
        printf("%20s = %d\n", tab[i].first.c_str(), tab[i].second);
}

int main ()
{
    yyparse();
    dict.print();
}
```

OFFTOPIC: [flex is not a GNU software](http://www.gnu.org/software/flex/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could add

```
 extern "C" int yyparse (void);
```

in your `main.cpp` file (and perhaps also in `parser.y`) or in some common `#include`-d header file.

And you really should use `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` to compile your code (or the parser generated C++ code).

Consider also using other C++ compatible open source [parser generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators), like [bisonc++](https://fbb-git.gitlab.io/bisoncpp/) or [carburetta](https://carburetta.com/) or [ANTLR](https://www.antlr.org/).

Comment: Adding it in both main.cpp and parser.y made it worked, thanks. But I still don't understand why I need to declare both as coming from C code since I'm compiling everything in C++. Could someone clarify this for me?

Comment: Unless you do something extra on the command line, gcc compiles `lex.yy.c` as a C file because that's what it's extension says it is. Same for `parse.tab.c`. And my guess is that those files wouldn't compile if you tried to do them as C++.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this questions will be helpful: [Difficulties during the compilation (g++, bison, flex) with yyparse();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431942/problem-during-the-compilation-g-bison-flex-with-yyparse) 
I had also a problem with yyparse().